# Offset and Partition - Kafka Sink Processor

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using kafka Topology forward to send a record to a kafka topic.

We were using a separate producer to publish the message earlier and we were able to grab the offset and partition of the message. Now we want to replace it with Context.forward.

How can we get the offset and partition of the record sent by Kafka Sink Processor using context.forward

Answer (score 0):

Publish message to topic in `producer.type=sync` mode. when you call `send()` method, it will return all the details you are looking.

Comment: Thanks, we are using a producer currently and want to change it to topology forward